# Python and cryptopals, Why is there an errror involving an int showing up, while I have no such integers around?

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm attempting to solve cryptopals exercises for cryptoanalysis. Right now, I am struggling with set 1, exercise 6 . [check here for some context](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6)

So far, my code looks like this:

```
with open("6.txt", 'r') as infile:
        b64_encoded = infile.readlines()


from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

import functools



ciphertext = b64decode('\n'.join([x.strip() for x in b64_encoded if x != ""]))

def hammingDistance(binary_seq_1, binary_seq_2): # calculating the hamming distances between to byte strings
   
    assert len(binary_seq_1) == len(binary_seq_2)
    dist = 0

    for bit1, bit2 in zip(binary_seq_1, binary_seq_2):
        diff = bit1 ^ bit2
        dist += sum([1 for bit in bin(diff) if bit == '1'])

    return dist

def xor(b1, b2): # SImply for XOR'ing
  b = bytearray(len(b1))
  for i in range(len(b1)):
    b[i] = b1[i] ^ b2[i]
  return b



def createChunks(ciphertext, k):
    res = []
    while len(ciphertext) >= k:
        res.append(ciphertext[:k])
        ciphertext = ciphertext[k:]
    return res

def sortByKeysizeAndProbability(c ):
    normalized_distances = []
    for KEYSIZE in range(2, 40):
        chunks = createChunks(c, KEYSIZE)


        score = 0 
        score = float(
            functools.reduce( lambda acc, tup : acc +  hammingDistance(tup[0],tup[1]), list(zip(chunks, chunks[1:])), 0)
        )

        score /= KEYSIZE
        score /= len(chunks) 

        normalized_distances.append(
            (KEYSIZE, score)
        )
    return  sorted(normalized_distances, key=lambda x: x[1])



print(sortByKeysizeAndProbability(ciphertext))
```

The function that is causing the trouble is `sortByKeysizeAndProbability()`, because it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dummy.py", line 74, in <module>
    print(sortByKeysizeAndProbability(ciphertext))
  File "dummy.py", line 49, in sortByKeysizeAndProbability
    functools.reduce( lambda acc, tup : acc +  hammingDistance(tup[0],tup[1]), list(zip(chunks, chunks[1:])), 0)
  File "dummy.py", line 49, in <lambda>
    functools.reduce( lambda acc, tup : acc +  hammingDistance(tup[0],tup[1]), list(zip(chunks, chunks[1:])), 0)
  File "dummy.py", line 21, in hammingDistance
    dist += sum([1 for bit in bin(diff) if bit == '1'])
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Hmm, it somehow seems that I am at some point trying to use my `hammingDistance` on  a integer. This does'nt make any sense to me, so I decided to see if I could recreate the issue.
After placing a few prints, I could tell that it was failing already in the first iteration of the loop, when `KEYSIZE = 2`.

So I thought that I could just recreate the conditions that caused the error like so:

```
chunked = createChunks(ciphertext, 2)

sum = functools.reduce( lambda acc, tup : acc +  hammingDistance(tup[0],tup[1]), list(zip(chunked, chunked[1:])), 0)

print(sum)
```

But strangely, this does'nt fail, it just outputs `9342`, which is what it should do.

But this is really weird to me, because the little experiment I wrote above, is exactly the same as the place that the code fails when I am calling `sortByKeysizeAndProbability()`. Can anyone tell me why the code fails in one case, but works in the other?

**update**

It was pointed out to me that I probably had some variable called "sum" standing somewhere, that was confusing things. Ths turned out to be correct, I don't quite understand how though.

Now, what happens is that when I attempt to load my ciphertext, and measure the hamming distance between blocks of it:

```
def hammingDistance(binary_seq_1, binary_seq_2): # calculating the hamming distances between to byte strings
   
    assert len(binary_seq_1) == len(binary_seq_2)
    dist = 0

    for bit1, bit2 in zip(binary_seq_1, binary_seq_2):
        diff = bit1 ^ bit2
        dist += sum([1 for bit in bin(diff) if bit == '1'])

    return dist
with open("6.txt", 'r') as infile:
        b64_encoded = infile.readlines()


from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

import functools

ciphertext = b64decode('\n'.join([x.strip() for x in b64_encoded if x != ""]))

chunked = createChunks(ciphertext, 2)


sums = functools.reduce( lambda acc, tup : acc +  hammingDistance(tup[0],tup[1]), list(zip(chunked, chunked[1:])), 0)

print(sums)
```

This error is thrown in my face:

```
  File "dummy.py", line 20, in hammingDistance
    diff = bit1 ^ bit2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'
```

Which also is strange, since my ciphertext is of `bytes` type.
How do I make my hamming distance function work?

Comment: Oh, have you been using `sum` as a variable?

Comment: Is there some other piece of code where you assigned an int to either `sum` or `bin`?  That would explain the error about an int not being callable on the line where you try to call functions by those names.

Comment: ah yes, i'll update the question